# Is it possible to avoid table view row selection in android titanium

Tags: android, titanium

How to disable table view row selection into in titanium for android application?
in iphone is possible by

```
selectionStyle:Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
```

and in android i tried

```
Titanium.UI.createTableView({ allowsSelection: false }); and
row.selectionStyle = 'none';
```

but it's not working..
if anyone have a solution please help it will much appreciate .

Answer (score 0):

set either

```
    selectedColor:'transparent'
```

or

```
touchEnabled:false
```

Answer (score -1):

in your xml file setfocusable, setclickable as false.

```
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
```

if you can use android code then try this

```
    tb.setFocusable(false);
    tb.setClickable(false);
    tb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

tb is a tablerow object.

Comment: thanks for reply but i am working in titanium (javascript) how to handle it in java script..

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    selectionStyle: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
});
```

when creating your row. This is covered in the documentation (located [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow) - try searching for the words 'selectionStyle' by hitting `ctrl+f` in your browser). This should remove any highlighting when clicking on a table row.